# Progress bar is not hidden where it is supposed to be hidden it shows continuesly

Tags: android, pagination, progress-bar

I am implementing pagination concept in my application it i fetch data by 15 from the data base when i have more than 15 data it works fine the progress bar works fine

The problem is : When there is only 4 or 5 records the progress bar is keep on progressing which should not run like that the progress bar should come only when i scroll to get more data

How can i fix it

```
    final RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(mContext);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
            recyclerView.setItemAnimator(null);
            parishNewsAdapter = new ParishNewsAdapter(recyclerView, listParishNews, mActivity, mContext);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(parishNewsAdapter);

            parishNewsAdapter.setOnLoadMoreListener(new OnLoadMoreListener() {
                @Override
                public void onLoadMore() {
                    finalList.add(null);
                    parishNewsAdapter.notifyItemInserted(finalList.size() - 1);

                    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            ArrayList<ParishNewsModel> mList = new ArrayList<>();
                            finalList.remove(finalList.size() - 1);
                            parishNewsAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(finalList.size());
                            index = index + 15;
                            int end = index + 1;
                            mList = tableHelper.getParishNews(end);
                            if (mList.size() == 0) {
                                ParishNewsAdapter.LoadingViewHolder.progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            }
                            parishNewsAdapter.addObjectToList(mList);
                            parishNewsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            parishNewsAdapter.setLoaded();
                        }
                    }, 1000);
                }
            });

This is where i just call the adapter where the progress should show when i swipe to see more data

here is my adapter 

private ArrayList<ParishNewsModel> parishList;
    ParishNewsModel parishNewsModel;
    Context mContext;
    private final int VIEW_TYPE_ITEM = 0;
    private final int VIEW_TYPE_LOADING = 1;
    private OnLoadMoreListener onLoadMoreListener;

    private boolean isLoading;
    private Activity activity;
    private int visibleThreshold = 5;
    private int lastVisibleItem, totalItemCount;
    int limit = 10;

    public ParishNewsAdapter(RecyclerView recyclerView, ArrayList<ParishNewsModel> parishList, Activity activity, Context mContext) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.parishList = parishList;
        this.mContext = mContext;

        final LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = (LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager();
        recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
                totalItemCount = linearLayoutManager.getItemCount();
                lastVisibleItem = linearLayoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition();
                if (!isLoading && totalItemCount <= (lastVisibleItem + visibleThreshold)) {
                    if (onLoadMoreListener != null) {
                        onLoadMoreListener.onLoadMore();
                    }
                    isLoading = true;
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void setOnLoadMoreListener(OnLoadMoreListener mOnLoadMoreListener) {
        this.onLoadMoreListener = mOnLoadMoreListener;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
//        return parishList.get(position) == null ? VIEW_TYPE_LOADING : VIEW_TYPE_ITEM;
        if (parishList.get(position) == null) {
            return VIEW_TYPE_LOADING;
        } else {
            return VIEW_TYPE_ITEM;
        }
    }


    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        if (viewType == VIEW_TYPE_ITEM) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(activity).inflate(R.layout.parish_news_reference_layout, parent, false);
            return new MyViewHolder(view);
        } else if (viewType == VIEW_TYPE_LOADING) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(activity).inflate(R.layout.lazy_load_progress_bar, parent, false);
            return new LoadingViewHolder(view);
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        if (holder instanceof MyViewHolder) {
            ParishNewsModel newsModel = parishList.get(position);
            MyViewHolder myViewHolder = (MyViewHolder) holder;
            myViewHolder.title.setText(newsModel.getTitleOfTheNews());
            myViewHolder.short_description.setText(Html.fromHtml(newsModel.getDescription()));
            myViewHolder.date_of_text.setText(Html.fromHtml(newsModel.getDateOfNews()));
            String str = newsModel.getParishNewsImage();
            Glide.with(mContext).load(str).thumbnail(Glide.with(mContext).load(R.drawable.jesus)).into(myViewHolder.circleImageView);
        } else if (holder instanceof LoadingViewHolder) {
            LoadingViewHolder loadingViewHolder = (LoadingViewHolder) holder;
            loadingViewHolder.progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            loadingViewHolder.progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
        }
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                parishNewsModel = parishList.get(position);
                AppUtils.model = parishNewsModel;
                if (AppUtils.model != null) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, ScrollingActivity.class);
                    mContext.startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView title, short_description, date_of_text;
        ImageView circleImageView;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title_parish_news);
            short_description = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.short_description);
            date_of_text = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.date_published);
            circleImageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.news_image);
        }
    }

    public static class LoadingViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public static ProgressBar progressBar;

        public LoadingViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            progressBar = (ProgressBar) itemView.findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return parishList == null ? 0 : parishList.size();

    }

    public void addObjectToList(ArrayList<ParishNewsModel> list) {
        parishList.addAll(list);
    }

    public void setLoaded() {
        isLoading = false;
    }
```

How can i move further please guide me

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the progressbar from adapter on onBindViewHolder and put in inside 
postDelayed. This is because when you scroll down onBindViewHolder will call again
and again and you set progress bar visible  inside it only.